# Filter the feed page post limit

Tags: query, rss

WordPress has a setting for the number of items shown in syndication feeds. I want to bypass that setting in a plugin and return a different number of items.

Here's what I am doing, but it's not working. Any idea why?

```
add_filter( 'init', 'rss_addfeed_add_feed' );

function rss_addfeed_add_feed() {
    $general_settings = get_option( 'rss_settings_general', 'rss' );
    if ( !empty( $general_settings ) && isset( $general_settings['custom_feed_url'] ) ) {
        $url = $general_settings['custom_feed_url'];
    }
    else $url = 'rss';
    add_feed( $url, 'rss_addfeed_do_feed' );
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}



function rss_addfeed_do_feed( $in ) {

    // Prepare the post query
    $rss_custom_feed_query = apply_filters(            
            'rss_custom_feed_query',
            array(
            'post_type'   => 'rss_feed_item', 
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => 4,
            'cache_results' => false,   // disable caching
        ) 

    );

    // Submit the query to get latest feed items
    query_posts( $rss_custom_feed_query );

    // Send content header and start ATOM output
    header('Content-Type: application/atom+xml');
    // Disabling caching
    header('Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate'); // HTTP 1.1.
    header('Pragma: no-cache'); // HTTP 1.0.
    header('Expires: 0'); // Proxies.
    echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="' . get_option('blog_charset') . '"?' . '>';
    ?>
    <feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
        <title type="text">Latest imported feed items on <?php bloginfo_rss('name'); ?></title>
        <?php
        // Start the Loop
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        ?>
        <entry>
            <title><![CDATA[<?php the_title_rss(); ?>]]></title>
            <link href="<?php the_permalink_rss(); ?>" />
            <published><?php echo get_post_time( 'Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z' ); ?></published>
            <content type="html"><![CDATA[<?php the_content(); ?>]]></content>
        </entry>
        <?php
        // End of the Loop
        endwhile;
        ?>
    </feed>
    <?php
}    


add_filter( 'post_limits', 'rss_custom_feed_limits' );

function rss_custom_feed_limits( $limit ) {
    if ( is_feed( ) ) { 
        return 'LIMIT 0, 3';   
    }
    return $limit;
}
```

Comment: It works from me. I tried `return 'LIMIT 0, 2';` (easily countable) and got 2 posts in the feed.

Comment: @s_ha_dum It only works if I add a parameter for 'posts_per_page' as in the updated example. It now fetches 4 items according to the parameter. So am I creating the custom feed in a non-WP way? What is causing the feed limit to fail?

Comment: I tried again. The `posts_where` filter alone works for me. All I can think is that there must be some other filter causing trouble. Switch themes and disable plugins.

Comment: So you're suggesting I try it out with posts_where filter instead of post_limits?

Comment: No. I misstyped. `posts_limits` is correct.

Comment: No solution then for now, I'll wait for other opinions.

Comment: I wouldn't expect "other options". What you are doing works in a vanilla install. You need to figure out what is making it _not work_-- almost certainly a plugin or your theme, so "switch themes and disable plugins". Does that help?